# Reading the Html of a webpage using java?

Tags: java

Is there anyway I could do this thing i'm trying to do

So I want to run my java program on a website
If I sees a certain text anywhere in the page 
It clicks on a link that is in the html code

Here is what I mean

Say the text i'm looking for is 
Banana and if it finds Banana on the page it goes to a 
 link in the html code
Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: You need a HTML parser for java. Search them and use them, but first read the documentations.

Comment: there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) because of it's css selectors

the code could then look somewhat like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("a");
for(Element e : elements) {
    if(e.text().contains("banana")) {
        String linkURL = e.attr("abs:href");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This demo perhaps should help you.

```
String demo = "<select id='list'><option value='0'>First value</option><option value='1'>Second value</option><option value='2'>Third value</option></select>";


        Document document = Jsoup.parse(demo);
        Elements options = document.select("select > option");

        for(Element element : options)
        {
           System.out.println(element.attr("value"));
        }
```

You would need to use `Jsoup` to parse html for more on it visit [this](http://jsoup.org/) link.

**Note :** I have used a `String` to parse you can directly connect to a url and parse the response html.